# python multiple stacked plots along y axis

Tags: python, plot, visualization, stacked

I have a binned data of an x-axis n-length vector and 3 y-axis n-length vector for 3 different histograms on the same x-axis.

Now I want this kind of stacked bar plot or any thing similar as below.

[image: chart]

The nearest I have found is `Qtiplot` (which is not python). It can generate exactly this kind of histogram plots. But it computes the histogram by itself and requires the actual data samples which are not present in my case (I only have the histogram itself).

Please note that I don't know python very well. So I don't have a clue from where I shall start, neither I am really in a mood to learn programming in python. I need this only to make a nice vector-graphics plot for my research thesis.

I have tagged `python` as I think python is the most obvious language. In case someone knows any better solution other than in python (but not Matlab, I cannot install that huge pile), I will thankfully add the proper tag.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

use matplotlib package in python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

apple_weight=[3,3,3,10,10,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,7,7,7]
banana_weight=[3,3,3,10,10,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,7,7,7]
mango_weight=[3,3,3,10,10,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,7,7,7]

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(312)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(313)
ax1.hist(apple_weight)
ax2.hist(banana_weight)
ax3.hist(mango_weight)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way that can share the y axis, specifically the ylabel?

Comment: instead of ax2=add_subplot(312) write ax2=ax.twinx()

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

apple_weight=[3,3,3,10,10,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,7,7,7]
banana_weight=[3,3,3,10,10,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,7,7,7]
mango_weight=[3,3,3,10,10,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,7,7,7]

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=ax1.twinx()
#only two y axes so the third list just add to either

ax1.hist(apple_weight)
ax2.hist(banana_weight)
ax1.hist(mango_weight)
plt.show()
```